# Spring Security authentication works for only one username and password

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using JDBC Authentication in Spring Security. I have two username-password pairs in MySQL database.

```
users
+----------+------------+---------+
| username | password   | enabled |
+----------+------------+---------+
| murat    | {noop}1a09 |       1 |
| test     | {noop}123  |       1 |
+----------+------------+---------+

authorities
+----------+-----------+
| username | authority |
+----------+-----------+
| murat    | USER      |
+----------+-----------+
```

But only first pair works on login. The second one gives the following error:

> Your login attempt was not successful, try again.
>
> Reason: Bad credentials

I've tried to login with Google Chrome. But didn't work.

Here is the code for authorization:

```java
package com.example.contactsapp.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ContactsAppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource securityDataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/logoutSuccessful");

    }
}
```

Comment: Please mention both username and password. (Attach Db screenshot) Add complete code of your security config class. I assume you removed code before posting?

Comment: I shared both users and authorities tables in database. And this is my security config class, it's done because of it is a simple app.

Comment: +1 for updating question. Actually i was confused with your question when posted. Now it is very clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please verify two things:

1) Verify that second user has roles/authorities associated with it.
2) Delete first user (so that only one user is present in DB). See if security is passing through as a second user.

Comment: Defining authority for the user in database solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Before checking complex scenarios, please check first password of the 2nd user. Set it to something simple like `123`, so that you cannot do any mistake. If it works with this simple password, it means the problem is related to Spring.

If it works with `123`, but doesn't work with your original password, check if you have any characters that are not part of ASCII, e.g. you use some special characters like `â, Ç, Ğ, Ö, Ü`. If you have such characters in your password, then the problem can be caused by specific code page of your database. To check that, write to console or to log your entered password (that you want to check) and the password from database. If they loom different, then there is problem with code page.

Comment: My 2nd user's password is ```{noop}123``` (without encryption) and the username is ```test```. It doesn't work with this user.

Answer (score -2):

Change function

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(securityDataSource);
    }
```

to

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon. I see no reason why adding queries to the JDBC datasource will fix the OP's problem. I also see no evidence of how you determined the OP's database schema to determine the correct queries...